regular polygons rotation among convex uniform polyhedra vertices : Is this chirality too?
CONTEXT
Among convex uniform polyhedra, 3 classes can be described with respectively 12, 24 and 60 vertices. They share the specific property of containing 3 polyhedra types each, one per vertex configuration, with a vertex degree of respectively 3, 4 and 5.




Types
Degree 3
Degree 4
Degree 5




Classes






12 vertices

Truncated tetrahedron
Cuboctahedron
Snub Tetrahedron (=Icosahedron)


24 vertices

Truncated octahedron
Rhombicuboctahedron
Snub Cube


60 vertices

Truncated icosahedron
Rhombicosidodecahedron
Snub Dodecahedron



There are only 3 degrees. There are only 3 polyhedra with degree 5 vertex configuration. There are only 3 classes.
QUESTION 1
The limitation to 3 vertex degree configurations looks trivial : with unitary edges and equidistance of the vertices to the center, degree 1 could only describe a segment, degree 2 could only describe regular polygons and degree 6 could only describe an infinite plane. But is it trivial ? And is there an explanation to why there are 3 such classes ?
PROPOSITION
Vertices can be grouped as non-adjacent regular polygons :

4 equilateral triangles, the center of which are the vertices of an inner tetrahedron, for the 12 vertices class.
6 squares, the center of which are the vertices of an inner octahedron, for the 24 vertices class.
12 pentagons, the center of which are the vertices of an inner icosahedron, for the 60 vertices class.

Then the polyhedral types inside the classes can be described with only the rotation angle of the regular polygons. Since there is no 2-edges regular polygon, and no uniform polyhedron could have its vertices grouped by 6 as non-adjacent regular hexagons, there could only be 3 classes.
There is a visual animation in this short video clip.
QUESTION 2
Is this rotation angle another kind of chirality ? Has it been formalized or named ?

I would add: 6 vertices, degree 3 = triangular prism, degree 4 = octahedron, degree 5 = not exist (can you prove?); 4 vertices, degree 3 = tetrahedron, degree 4 or 5 = not exist.

yes, but the purpose is to describe classes that do include all 3 degree types
